# For Date serialization: What is the equivalent annotation of @XmlJavaTypeAdapter from JAXB2 to jackson-dataformat-xml?

Tags: xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a Spring Web Application working with the `4.3.6` version. It works with XML and JSON until some point.

- For Json I use Jackson.
- For XML I used to work with `JAXB2`, but not anymore because it does not support Generic collections

A Generic collection is represented such as:

```
public class GenericCollection<T> {

        private Collection<T> collection;

        public GenericCollection(){
            this.collection = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        }

        public GenericCollection(Collection<T> collection){
            this.collection = collection;
        }

...
```

Thus for `XML` the application moved from `JABX2` to `Jackson` working with the [jackson-dataformat-xml](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml) project

To serialize a `Date` for JSON I use:

```
public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(value);
        gen.writeString(formattedDate);
    }

}
```

And used how:

```
@JsonProperty("fecha")
@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}
```

For XML, when `JAXB2` was used, again for `Date` serialization the following *was* used:

```
public class XmlDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return dateFormat.parse(v);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        return dateFormat.format(v);
    }

}
```

And used how:

```
@JsonProperty("fecha")
@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
@XmlElement(name="fecha")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(XmlDateAdapter.class)
public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}
```

Due this migration from `Jaxb2` to `jackson-dataformat-xml` I know that the latter *ignores* the `JAXB2` annotations. Thus working now with:

```
@JsonProperty("fecha")
@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="fecha")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(XmlDateAdapter.class)
public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}
```

Therefore from `@XmlElement(name="fecha")` to `@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="fecha")`

The problem now is the that `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(XmlDateAdapter.class)` is ignored too.

**Question**:

What is the equivalent annotation of `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` from `JAXB2` to `jackson-dataformat-xml`