# Common @Bean configuration for serialization for MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter and MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter

Tags: json, xml, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

For a Spring Web Application working with Jackson for `XML` and `JSON` through:

- [MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html)
- [MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.html)

These classes are used for **Rest** purposes and each one are configured through a `@Bean` method and both use the following:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder(){
    Jackson2Ob jectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.simpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return builder;
}
```

For `Date` serialization is *mandatory* use:

```
@JsonProperty("fecha")
@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(XmlDateAdapter.class)
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="fecha")
public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}
```

I want to know if is possible avoid these `@JsonSerialize` and `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotations and **trust** through a central `@Bean` method that offers a configuration that should be used for **both** these `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` converters; where the `Date` 'serialization' should be applied from that configuration. Consider the same about 'formatting' numbers such as `BigDecimal` and currency too.

Currently with the code shown above I must use `@JsonSerialize` and `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` mandatorily.

**Note**: for Jackson XML, `jackson-dataformat-xml` is used instead of `JAXB 2` due a limitation about of Generic Collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am totally misunderstanding the context here, you can configure jackson Object mapper to use JaxbAnnotationIntrospector as well. With that Jackson will respect the jaxb annotations while marshalling/unmarshalling.

Usually the configuration for that looks something like this:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder(){
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    AnnotationIntrospector annotationIntrospector =  AnnotationIntrospector.pair(
            new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(),

            new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector()
    );
    builder.annotationIntrospector(annotationIntrospector);
    // This is to make jackson respect @XmlElementWrapper annotation and use wrapper name as the property name
    builder.defaultUseWrapper(true);
    return builder;
}
```

And your entity date field will look like:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(XmlDateAdapter.class)
@XmlElement(value = "fetcha") // This is not mandatory to add. If your class is annnotated with @XmlRootElement annotation, by default the field name will be picked up as the name of the element.
public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}
```

If you want to get rid of `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` altogether and just want it to be serialized the way you want in json, you can create a custom json serializer  and deserializer classes extending jackson's JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer.

One such example of a custom serializer from [Jackson custom date serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247767/jackson-custom-date-serializer) (I modified this to not rely on a custom annotation and hence to not implement ContextualSerializer)

```
 public static class CustomDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>
            {
        private final String format;

        private CustomDateSerializer(final String format) {this.format = format;}

        public CustomDateSerializer() {this.format = null;}

        @Override
        public void serialize(
                final Date value, final JsonGenerator jgen, final SerializerProvider provider)
                throws IOException {
            jgen.writeString(new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(value));
        }
```

Similarly, you will need to create a custom Deserializer as well if you intend to deserialize Date json element to Date object. Then register them for Date class with Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.

```
builder.serializerByType(Date.class, new CustomDateSerializer());
builder.deserializerByType(Date.class, new CustomDateDeSerializer());
```

Comment: Thanks by suggestion, but I had a situation where now `JAXB2` is not used anymore, now is `jackson-dataformat-xml` used. More details in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682955/for-date-serialization-what-is-the-equivalent-annotation-of-xmljavatypeadapter

Comment: The point is _avoid_ use `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`, the `@XmlElement(value = "fetcha")` must remain, and your `jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()` method should define the central `Date` format. That's is the _main_ request

Comment: Edited my answer. You will need to create a custom serializer (as shown in answer) and register it with your object mapper builder for Date class. You can also take a look at this for an example of custom Json Serializer: https://dzone.com/articles/how-serialize-javautildate

Comment: Thanks, I will test the code soon as I can, just curious if `MyDateSerializer` declaration is the same referred through `new CustomDateSerializer()` sentences. I hope the `builder.serializerByType` and `builder.deserializerByType` work for `XML` too.

Comment: Yea. Sorry, It was a typing mistake. And no, it will not work for xml because this is being configured only for jackson object mapper.

If you want it to be consistent for xml and json (which I recommend and mentioned in my initial answer), you should keep `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation with a custom adapter that provides the date format and jackson will respect that because of the JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.